# AngularJS Slider Range change event only when pointer release

Tags: angularjs

I am using Angular slider https://github.com/PopSugar/angular-slider for min and max range selection. 
I used the change method provided in the slider directive.
The problem I am facing is its calling the JS function myChange() from the point I start sliding the pointer.
So my function is getting called unnecessarily .
I want to call the function only when I release the pointer in the slider bar.

Used code : `<slider floor="1000" ceiling="100000" ng-model-low=minPackagePrice ng-model-high="maxPackagePrice" change="myChange()"></slider>`

Comment: I'm not familiar with that slider, but the Angular Material slider works quite well.

Comment: yes its working fine .But I want to call my JS function on release of the slider range button.What change in the used slider is doing its calling the JS function while I am  sliding over the range bar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<slider floor="1000" ceiling="100000" ng-model-low=minPackagePrice ng-model-high="maxPackagePrice" ng-mouseup="myChange()"></slider>
```